Cannot force inline-block div to fill remaining width of parent div?
I have seen Fill up the remaining width inside inline-block parent div - but I still do not get how to make the below example work - I want the canvas_container_inner to fill remaining width of the main_container parent - but unfortunately, it has width 0:


#main_container { border: 1px solid #000; width:100%; height: 9em; position: relative; }
#info { display: inline-block; width: 8em; border: 1px solid #F00; height: 100%; }
#info > div:nth-child(1) { padding-bottom: 1em; }
#axis_labels { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid #F00; text-align: right; height: 100%; }
#axis_labels_flex { display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%; }
#axis_labels_flex > div:nth-child(1) { flex: 1 1 auto; border: 1px solid #FF0; }
#canvas_container { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid #F00; height: 100%; }
#canvas_container_inner { min-width: 100%; }
#canvas { width: 100%; }
<div id="main_container">
  <div id="info">
    <div id="title">Hello world</div>
    <div id="test_block">
      <div><code>testing</code></div>
      <div><input type="text" id="tf_test" size="6"></input></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="axis_labels">
    <div id="axis_labels_flex">
      <div>lbl 1</div>
      <div>label 0</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="canvas_container">
    <div id="canvas_container_inner">
      <!-- <canvas id="canvas"></canvas> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



And I do not really understand what causes the width of canvas_container_inner to be zero, as main_container does have a width: 100% defined?
Why does this canvas_container_inner zero width happen, and how do I make this (canvas_container_inner to fill the remaining available width) work?
EDIT: as for the close vote, "needs to clarify the problem", I don't see what is unclear in:

I want the canvas_container_inner to fill remaining width of the main_container parent - but unfortunately, it has width 0

... but here is an image, maybe it helps:


Thankfully, I can post some sort for an answer before this questions gets closed, which was more less trial and error inspired by https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/747598/CSS-Resize-inline-block-fill-remaining-space-on-li - the trick is:

main_container needs to be display: table;
info needs to be display: table-cell;
axis_labels needs to be, for some reason, display: inline-block; - else it will stretch to fill available width - and width: max-content;
canvas_container needs to be display: table-cell; and width: 100%;



#main_container { border: 1px solid #000; width:100%; height: 9em; position: relative; display: table; }
#info { display: table-cell; width: 8em; border: 1px solid #F00; height: 100%; }
#info > div:nth-child(1) { padding-bottom: 1em; }
#axis_labels { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid #F00; text-align: right; height: 100%; width: max-content; }
#axis_labels_flex { display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%; }
#axis_labels_flex > div:nth-child(1) { flex: 1 1 auto; border: 1px solid #FF0; }
#canvas_container { display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid #F00; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
#canvas_container_inner { min-width: 100%; }
#canvas { width: 100%; }
<div id="main_container">
  <div id="info">
    <div id="title">Hello world</div>
    <div id="test_block">
      <div><code>testing</code></div>
      <div><input type="text" id="tf_test" size="6"></input></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="axis_labels">
    <div id="axis_labels_flex">
      <div>lbl 1</div>
      <div>label 0</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="canvas_container">
    <div id="canvas_container_inner">
      <!-- <canvas id="canvas"></canvas> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



